# String Loop to Form a Variable name in R

Tags: r

```
calld=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*50,0,1),1000,50))

for (x in names(calld)) {
   assign(paste("calld$",x,sep=""),pnorm(get(paste("calld$",x,sep="")),0,1,lower.tail=T,log.p=F))
    }
Error in get(paste("calld$", x, sep = "")) : object 'calld$X1' not found
```

Am I using the `get` function correctly?? I am trying to concatenate the names of the data set  via a loop and paste of it's existing valued by passing the values through a `pnorm` (cumulative normal distribution function). But I keep getting an error. The function works when I call the variable names in the "`calld`" dataframe. The problem is the concentration process of creating the loop. Where am I going wrong? I appreciate your help

**Update::**

I took your advice guys and reedited the loop, to.

```
for (n in names(calld)) {

get("calld")[[n]]=pnorm(get("calld")[[n]],0,1,lower.tail=T,log.p=F)

}

Error in get("calld")[[n]] = pnorm(get("calld")[[n]], 0, 1, lower.tail = T,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

But now I am getting this new error. So everything on the right hand side of the equation in the loop when I tested it it works. The error arises when I set it the value equal to itself, replacing the prior values.

Comment: You cannot use `paste` to construct a call to `$`. Learn to use "[[".

Comment: And unlearn using `assign`/`get`!

Comment: the edit suggests you haven't quite got the point yet, I think ... @mnel's answer completely solves your problem.  You don't need to use `assign()` or `get()` at all (and shouldn't).

Comment: Indeed, @BenBolker. There is no need for **`get`** or `assign`.  `calld[[n]] <- pnorm(calld[[n]], 0,1,TRUE,FALSE)` will do what you want (but be highly inefficient as a copy of `calld` is made everytime you call `[[<-`. Only a single copy is made by my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have mercy on kittens!

You can't use `assign` this way, nor `get`.

```
 calld[] <- lapply(calld, pnorm, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Explanantion:  `calld[]<-` replaces  all existing columns of `calld` (whilst retaining the structure as a `data.frame`) with the results of `lapply(calld, pnorm, mean = 0, sd = 1)`  which cycles through all columns of `calld`, applying `pnorm` on each one.

```
 library(fortunes)
 fortune(312)
```

> The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like any other  magic if used incorrectly is likely to do the programmatic equivalent of turning yourself into a toad.
>
> -- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to access a column whose name is stored in y via x$y rather than x[[y]])
>
> R-help (February 2012)

Comment: +1 for saving the kittens.  I'll have to remember `fortune(312)` (or `fortune("toad")` if I forget the number). Maybe worth pointing out that `calld[]` is necessary to preserve the structure of `calld`; otherwise it turns into a list of vectors (rather than a data frame)

Comment: Leave those kitty's alone!! lol thank you for your help BondedDust and Mnel!!